# Where is the segmentation fault in this program?

Tags: segmentation-fault

All this is trying to do is putting the address of shortest string at the beginning and address of longest string at the end of array, but I can't see what is wrong with it. When I run it on linux I get 'segmentation fault'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fx(char* t[], int n);

int main(void) {
    char*t[]= {"horse", "elephant", "cat", "rabbit"};
    int n, i;
    n = sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]);
    fx(t, n);
    printf("shortest is %s, longest is %s\n", t[0], t[n-1]);

}

void fx(char* t[], int n) {
    int i;
    char* temp, len0, len1, len;
    len0 = strlen(t[0]); /* lenght of first string*/
    len1 = strlen(t[n+1]); /*lenght of last string*/
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        len = strlen(t[i]); /*temporary lenght if ith string*/
        if( len < len0 ) {
            temp = t[0];  /* if shorter, swap places with first*/
            t[0] = t[i];
            t[i] = temp;
        }
        else if(len > len1) {  /* if larger, swap places with last*/
            temp = t[n-1]; 
            t[n-1] = t[i];
            t[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `len1 = strlen(t[n+1]); /*lenght of last string*/` Shouldn't this be `n-1`?

Answer (score 0):

Array are [0....n-1]

```
len1 = strlen(t[n+1]); /*lenght of last string*/
```

should be

```
len1 = strlen(t[n-1]); /*lenght of last string*/
```

len0, len1 and len must be int, not char* since they hold the len of the strings

Comment: ... You're completely right, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @user2006562, FYI, since C does not implement automatic [bounds checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking), such code results in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).